# Using Spring's RedisTemplate with KEEPTTL option (with Lettuce library)

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, ttl, lettuce

I have a String [`RedisTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:template) to access REDIS. Underneath there is a connection that I get through a `LettuceConnectionFactory`.

I would like to accomplish the equivalent to these REDIS commands with the RedisTemplate instance.

```
set my_key new_value keepttl
```

What I have now is this:

```
RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = getMyRedisTemplate();
final ValueOperations<String, String> ops = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
ops.set("my_key", "new_value");
```

But if I do this, I loose the `ttl` previously set.

On the other hand, if I do this:

```
RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = getMyRedisTemplate();
final ValueOperations<String, String> ops = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
Long expire = redisTemplate.getExpire("my_key");
ops.set("my_key", "new_value", expire);
```

I feel like I am doing an extra unnecessary roundtrip to REDIS. That's what's the `KEEPTTL` is all about. Preventing this.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LUA.

```
RedisScript script = RedisScript.of("return redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], 'KEEPTTL')");
redisTemplate.execute(script, Collections.singletonList("my_key"), "new_value");
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for something simpler. :( but thanks a lot for the info anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I use ***Redisson***. It nicely integrates with Spring Data Redis.
It has built-in option for setting value along with ttl.

https://github.com/redisson/redisson